# How do I change the Array in place when prototyping

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I'm writing a custom sort function that I'm prototyping into Array. (PLEASE don't post answers explaining to me how I shouldn't bother prototyping into Array for whatever reason you feel prototyping into Array isn't a good idea).

so, my method looks like this:

```
//method
Array.prototype.mySort = function(memberName, ascOrDesc){
    var labelRow = this.shift();   
    var ret = this.sort((function (a,b){
        if(ascOrDesc > 0)
            return (a[memberName] > b[memberName])?1:-1; 
        return (a[memberName] < b[memberName])?1:-1;    
    }));    
    ret.unshift(labelRow)
    return ret;
}
```

Notice how this.shift() will affect the Array IN PLACE.

However, I'm not clear on how this is accomplished. If I wanted to write my own `myShift` method, at some point I'd need to say something to the effect of

```
this = this.myShift();
```

which is obviously illegal.

So, I'm trying to understand how shift() gets access to the array's members and is able to remove the first one in-place. And if I'm allowed to do something analogous, or if this is somehow baked in and not available to me to use.

Comment: Adding methods into `Array.prototype` is frequently a very good idea!

Comment: there are mutative array methods that can modify this: splice, unshift, shift, pop, push, sort, and reverse. maybe more. contrast with slice and concat, which always return new arrays.

Comment: You mean it uses it like a reference?

Comment: @dandavis, I understand... so my question is *how do they accomplish the mutative result? What's the syntax for doing this since I can't assign to `this`?

Comment: you have to use a combination of the methods i mentioned to leave the array how it should be. there are no other options afaik. You can set this.length=0 and manually build up a whole new array without breaking the object ref.

Comment: Many methods are "destructive", in that they operate on the original object rather than producing a new one. In fact, `sort` and `unshift` are *also* destructive, so you don't even need a `ret` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the array using `this` inside the method.

You can for example implement the shift method as:

```
Array.prototype.myShift = function() {
  if (this.length == 0) return null;
  var result = this[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < this.length; i++) {
    this[i-1] = this[i];
  }
  this.length--;
  return result;
};
```

Comment: It'd didn't occur to me that `this` can be used with brackets to get at the members... seems really obvious in hindsight.

Comment: so, changing `length` to a lower number will delete the remaining items`?

Comment: yeah, that's a property of Array. You can delete the tail by modifying the length.

Comment: @Guffa, actually in hindsight-hindsight, this is highly UN-intuitive because normally I expect the [] members of an object to be, well... the members of the object `this['splice']` `this['shift']` etc.  So, in this quirky case, the brackets play the double role of giving me the hash access to the members, but ALSO giving me the numerically indexed access to the array elements.  I'm delighted that it works that way, but there's no obvious reason that it *should! :).  I guess in the case of Array, I should have noticed that that's how it works, but I take it for granted after 15 years of use.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: Yes, arrays are a bit strange that way. Note that the array looks at the value, not the type, so `this["0"]` accesses the item of the array, not the property named `0`. Any object can have a property named `0`, except an array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't assign to `this`. This means you can't do things like this:

```
Array.prototype.myShift = function() {
    this = this.slice(1);
};
```

This is because `Array.prototype.slice` returns a new array and does not modify the old array. Other methods, however, such as `Array.prototype.splice`, *do* modify the old array. So you can do something like this:

```
Array.prototype.myShift = function() {
    return this.splice(0, 1)[0];
};
```

This will have exactly the same behaviour as the standard `Array.prototype.shift` method. It modifies the current array, so you can do this:

```
var labelRow = this.myShift();
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but this doesn't actually address the problem of modifying the elements in-place.

Comment: Well, I have no idea what you mean by "in-place". This does precisely the same as the function you refer to above.

Comment: sorry... what I mean is that rather than getting a copy of the array I'm looking to actually modify the array members WITHIN the function. I am not looking to write my own `shift`, I only used that as an example of how it affects the array directly, rather than returning a copy with the new values (a la splice). As per another answer, this is called "mutive" (learned something new there as well). :)

Comment: This function does that. As does `shift`. As does `splice`. Read the documentation. Or my answer.

Comment: ok, I'm not sure how I can be any clearer (and really it doesn't matter cause I got my answer) but your answer is simply addressing the matter of shifting and splicing which I don't actually care about. What I wanted was to know how I can alter the array members within my prototyped function. The solution was to access them directly via their [] index, thus affecting them "in-place" within the method I'm writing.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, yeah, you can treat `this` as a reference to the array just as you would with any other variable name. `this.slice` is, after all, just the same as `this['slice']`. Glad you've solved your question.